# Root of an exponential equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, asymptotics, roots

Let $0 \le a \le 1$ and $-\infty < b < \infty$. I am looking for a solution of the exponential equation.

$$
a^x + abx = 0.
$$

I guess closed form expression of the root in terms of $a$ and $b$ may not be there. In that case, an asymptotic expansion of the root in terms of $a$ and $b$ would be just as fine.

Comment: For an asymptotic expansion, it would be useful to know if $a$ or $b$ is close to some value; e.g. $a\to0$ or $a\to1$ or $b\to0$ or $|b|\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
a^x+abx&=0\\
abx&=-e^{\log(a)x}\\
abx\,e^{-\log(a)x}&=-1\\
-\log(a)x\,e^{-\log(a)x}&=\frac{\log(a)}{ab}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, we can use the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) to get $-\log(a)x$:
$$
\begin{align}
-\log(a)x&=\mathrm{W}\left(\frac{\log(a)}{ab}\right)\\
x&=-\frac1{\log(a)}\mathrm{W}\left(\frac{\log(a)}{ab}\right)
\end{align}
$$
$\mathrm{W}(x)$ has real values for $x\ge-\frac1e$. For non-negative $x$, there is one real branch. For negative $x$, there are two real branches (which coincide at $-\frac1e$).

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ is sufficient close to $1$ and $x$ is assumed small, then we may write

$$a^x \sim 1+ (\ln{a}) x$$

Then the solution of the equation is

$$x=-\frac{1}{a b+\ln{a}}$$

For $x$ to be sufficiently small, assume the error in the exponential approximation is $\epsilon$; then

$$\left | \frac12 x^2 \ln^2{a}\right| < \epsilon \implies |x| < \frac{\sqrt{2 \epsilon}}{|\ln{a}|} $$